# Delete words from string via array based on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, str-replace

I have a very basic "filter" for strings, where words get deleted based on array content.

```
$delete = array("bad", "words", "delete");
$string= str_replace($delete , '', $string);
```

This works, no problems, but I want to make it so that it makes a $delete2 array based on a database. This is what I have:

```
$delete2= array();
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE type='delete' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$delete2[] = $row['delete'];
}
```

Now if I output this code:

```
$delete = array("bad", "words", "delete");
$string= str_replace($delete , '', $string);
$string= str_replace($delete2 , '', $string);
```

the second str_replace doesnt replace anything. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `$delete2` is not empty/holds the data you want?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos: ```str_replace``` can accept arrays for both the search and replace parameter. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: just print delete2 and show the structure

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thanks, it was my mistake, checked it!

Comment: The 2nd str_replace is working on the $string that has already been processed. In your code, with both replaces, assign it to a different variable. Like ```$str_result1 = ... ``` for the 1st one.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Comment: @crashtest are you saying that your `words` table has a column called `delete` (a keyword) and a column called `type` (a keyword)?  Can you confirm that your are getting a resultset / filled `$delete2` array?  I know I'd be using some different column names.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd str_replace is working on the $string that has already been processed. In your code, with both replaces, assign it to a different variable. Like `$str_rslt1 = ...` for the 1st one.

```
$delete2= array();
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE type='delete' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $delete2[] = $row['delete'];
}

$delete = array("bad", "words", "delete");
$str_rslt1 = str_replace($delete , '', $string);
$str_rslt2 = str_replace($delete2 , '', $string);
echo "<p>Result 1: $str_rslt1</p>\n";
echo "<p>Result 2: $str_rslt2</p>\n";
```

Also, use mysqli functions instead of mysql functions. mysqli is depreciated and subject to SQL injection. Lookup prepared statements and mysqli for more info.

Comment: Currently I have more than one "hard coded" array for keywords to delete just like the $delete array above and it works fine like this:
$string= str_replace($brands, '', $string);
$string= str_replace($thickness, '', $string);
$string= str_replace($materials, '', $string);
so the error must be where $delete2 is?!

Comment: You could just add the db delete words to your hard coded array, and so a single str_replace. Did you try the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was dumb. $row['delete']; does not exist in my table, I wasn't paying enough attention. Code works as intended.